What is the most efficient way to pack elements in AVX?
Consider we have 16 * 256i data in 16 m256i registers ix[16], and I want to pack them in the following way.
Data details:
ix[0] : a0, a1, a2, ... , a30, a31
ix[1] : b0, b1, b2, ... , b30, b31
..
ix[15] : z0, z1, z2, ... , z30, z31

Expectations:
consecutive mem:
a0, b0, c0, ..., z0, a1, b1, c1, ..., z1, a2, ..., a31, ..., z31.

Apparently _mm256_extract_epi8 can do this, but I think there must be a more efficient way, please answer if got some idea. Thanks a lot!

If I'm reading your question correctly, what you're looking for is a 16x32 transpose of byte elements.  Usually vpunpcklbw is a useful part of that, but search on "avx2 byte transpose" should hopefully find something.
